# How can I resolve this issue I have with creating an Ec2 on terraform please?

Tags: python, java, node.js, json, regex-group

The details are thus;

```
 Error: No configuration files
│ 
│ Plan requires configuration to be present. Planning without a configuration would mark everything for
│ destruction, which is normally not what is desired. If you would like to destroy everything, run plan with the
│ -destroy option. Otherwise, create a Terraform configuration file (.tf file) and try again.
```

Have try to resolve it with alias "env" but it does not seem to be go.

Comment: As the error suggests it is not able to find .tf file in the current directory.

Comment: What do *any* of the tags have to do with your question?  Is this a *programming* question at all?

Comment: (And how does the question demonstrate research effort?  How is it useful and clear?   What command did you run? What args?  An EC2 *what* ...)